# How can I notify an admin when a user is contacted?

Tags: forms, emails

On my Drupal 7 site, I have a user contact form.  How can I alter the form so that an admin is notified when the form is submitted?

Comment: use webform for any customization

Comment: Thank you for your response minymirza. I do not have webform installed, but entityforms. Also is there a way to assign (or attach) an entityform to each user2 profile, so it emails the owner of the profile and the admin? I asked this before here on stackexchange without luck, so I finally eneded up sticking to the sitewaide user contact form. I'm pretty stuck with this issue since the website owner wants to be notified when a user is contacted from his website...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a custom module

```
hook_form_alter() yourForm.
```

Add custom submit handler, it will run alongside with your defaut submit

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'yourSubmitFunction';
```

Inside your custom submit handler use drupal_mail() or any other result you need

```
function yourSubmitFunction($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_mail()
  ....
}
```

Note: the form_state array contains all the submited values.

Comment: This is how I would do it :-) +1

Comment: @Pan I have implemented hook_alter_form like this: 
function request_info_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
 if($form_id == "contact_personal_form"){
     $form['#submit'][] = 'request_information';
   }
}

function request_information($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user, $language;
  
  $site_email = variable_get('site_mail', '');
  $to = $site_email;
  drupal_mail('contact', 'page_mail', $to, language_default(), $values, $from);
}   ---and it's sending the email to the admin, but not the message, I thought the form state array contained all the submitted values...A tip?...

Comment: $values should be something like $form_state['values']['element_that_contains_message'] ...

Comment: @Pan Yep! Was missing $values = $form_state['values'];
  $values['sender'] = $user;
  $values['sender']->name = $values['name'];
  $values['sender']->mail = $values['mail'];
  $values['subject'] = $form_state['values']['subject'];
  $values['message'] = $form_state['values']['message'];
  $from = $values['name']; Now works as magic! Thanks!